# Does Documentum D2 provide a Rest API that allows the creation of a Virtual Document using a Life Cycle?

Tags: rest, lifecycle, documentum, documentum-dql, documentum-d2

We have a 'New Content' dialog in the Documentum D2 application where users must select a template. Afterward, the system generates a document using predefined Life Cycle processes in the backend. However, I'm looking to automate this process using a Rest API.

I attempted to use the copy feature, but it resulted in creating a duplicate document with identical properties.